# How to fix high contrast setting for text control in wix toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer, accessibility, high-contrast

Disabled user control in installer GUI is not being highlighted (in green border) in high contrast windows theme, but password controls works correctly. But configuration for both elements is same.

How to fix that or is it even possible to fix that in Wix?

```
<Control Id="ProxyUserNameEdit" Type="Edit" X="30" Y="150" Width="200" Height="17" Help="|" Sunken="yes"  Property="USER">
 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA["1" = "1"]]></Condition>
```

```
<Control Id="ProxyPasswordEdit" Type="Edit" X="30" Y="192" Width="200" Height="17" Help="|" Sunken="yes" Password="yes" Property="PASSWORD">
 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA["1" = "1"]]></Condition>
```

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with this important feature I am afraid, but please let us see the whole source for that dialog? Just edit your question and add? First impulse: did you try to add the attribute [`"TabSkip"`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/control.html) and set it to `no` for both controls?

Comment: Would TabSkip have a effect on looks of control. Both the controls are defined exactly same way, only difference is password="yes"

Comment: so when focus moves to the username field, it does **not** get a green focus ring?  but when focus moves to the password field, it **does** get a green focus ring?  i assume your screenshot is when the password field had focus because it's showing the green ring.  what does it look like when the username has focus?